# How to restore my System Python 2.6 on OS X 10.6.8

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard

I was messing around with Python in Library/Frameworks as well as System/Library/Frameworks. I deleted System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.6. Then I copied in the equivalent directory from Library/Frameworks...

Will that break my OSX? If so, is there any way to restore the system python setup.

Not sure if this is relevant:

```
$ which python
usr/local/bin
$ python -V
Python 2.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a subtlety between /Library and /System/Library that I do not understand.  Therefore, this answer is flawed.

However.  Even with that gap, I suggest you do this.

1. Backup your data.  All of it.  Backup any apps you installed.
2. Buy 10.7 Lion.
3. Install.  I don't think you need to do a "fresh" install.  But some Mac users strongly suggest fresh installs of each new OS  release.
4. Restore your files.

Don't delete Python.  iLife (for one) requires it.

Comment: I feared this would be the only sensible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with the pre-installed python. It will break dependencies on your mac. It happened to me, I had to re-install to fix it. A better thing to do is to install a new version of python.